# Downloaded divshot files do not display as shown in divshot

Tags: divshot

I created a simple mockup of a page in DivShot:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4255620/page-in-divshot.png

I then downloaded the files. When I view the same page in a browser, the "search" pane is clipped by the navigation bar:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4255620/page-displayed-locally.png

Why are they different? What am I doing wrong? (I can fix this by editing the <body> tag to <body style="padding-top: 50px">, but this still doesn't explain why the page displays differently in divshot than in my local environment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, a quick way to fix it is just to add 60px of padding to the body:

```
body{ padding-top: 60px; }
```

We have a fix for this issue in the pipeline, expect it in the next few weeks!